# webpage to excel: extracting data from a ranking across many pages

Tags: excel, http, text

This is my first post and I am quite noobish!
Please excuse the unsavvyness of my question.

What I would like to do is extract the rankings from http://www.appdata.com/leaderboard/app_store_apps?id=3781-top-free-apps

here is an extract from the html

```
   <tr>
          <td style="width:10px;" valign="top">3.</td>
          <td class="name" style="width:360px;" align="left">





              <img alt="The Official Masters Tournament" height="16" src="http://a5.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/082/Purple/v4/7b/db/9e/7bdb9e4a-7dea-6cb9-e46f-eba29f1d68a3/yzdmBWtm3FestDVRYi9gYg-temp-upload.mislucox.175x175-75.jpg" width="16" />
              &nbsp;
              <a href="/ios_apps/apps/4435931-the-official-masters-tournament">The Official Masters Tournament</a>                

          </td>

          <td align="right" style="padding-right:10px">

            3

          </td>







            <td align="right" style="color:black;; padding-right:10px">=</td>


      </tr>

      <tr>
          <td style="width:10px;" valign="top">4.</td>
          <td class="name" style="width:360px;" align="left">
              <img alt="LEGO® Ninjago: Rise of the Snakes" height="16" src="http://a1.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/063/Purple/v4/d8/3d/e0/d83de000-7ba6-1b0c-837a-7a7f6ca9dccf/mzl.ttwivuek.175x175-75.jpg" width="16" />
              &nbsp;
              <a href="/ios_apps/apps/4397421-lego-ninjago-rise-of-the-snakes">LEGO® Ninjago: Rise of the Snakes</a>

          </td>

          <td align="right" style="padding-right:10px">

            4

          </td>

            <td align="right" style="color:black;; padding-right:10px">=</td>

      </tr>
```

and export it to excel.

I could copy paste (to excel), but the ranking is many pages long. 
I would need to copy, paste, click next page, copy, paste...

Can you think of a solution?
Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In response to your comment, here is a way you can show all pages in one sheet without the buttons.  I want to note, though, that while I tried, I couldn't seem to get rid of the table headers for subsequent pages that were returned.  This code will add each page of the site below the previous page so you can just scroll all the way down.  After this is run once, I would recommend using the "Refresh All" button instead of running the code again.

Edit: I modified the code to include a "copy values only" to another sheet so you can save the data statically.

Here is the code:

```
Sub createQueryTable()
    Dim wsQuery As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim wsValues As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim q As Excel.QueryTable
    Dim destination As Excel.Range
    Dim connection As String
    Dim lastRow As Long, currentRow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Set wsValues = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    Set wsQuery = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add

    Set destination = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
    connection = "URL;http://www.appdata.com/leaderboard/app_store_apps?fanbase=0&id=3781-top-free-apps&metric_select=mau&page="
    lastRow = 1

    For i = 1 To 100
        If (lastRow <> currentRow) Then
            currentRow = lastRow
        Else
            Exit For
        End If
        Set q = wsQuery.QueryTables.Add(connection:=connection & i _
                                        , destination:=wsQuery.Cells(currentRow, "A") _
                                        )
        q.Name = "app_store_apps?fanbase=0&id=3781-top-free-apps&metric_select=mau&page=" & i
        q.WebTables = "8"
        q.RowNumbers = False
        q.BackgroundQuery = True

        If (currentRow = 1) Then
            q.FieldNames = True
        Else
            q.FieldNames = False
        End If

        q.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

        lastRow = getNextAvailableRow(wsQuery, "A")
    Next

    wsQuery.Range("A1", wsQuery.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)).Copy
    wsValues.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    wsValues.Activate
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub

Function getNextAvailableRow(ByRef ws As Excel.Worksheet, ByRef columnLetter As String) As Long
    Dim r As Long
    r = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, columnLetter).End(xlUp).Row
    getNextAvailableRow = r + 1
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you so much joseph4tw, this is brillant. It works great, very helpful. In order to track history of this ranking over time, do you suggest I do something? Maybe I should run a script on a computer that stays up everyday of the year? Do you recommend a language?

Comment: I tried to use the same formula for the same website, but in a different category (health and fitness). The web page becomes: http://www.appdata.com/leaderboard/app_store_apps?list_select=app_store&type=Free&device=iPhone&country_id=95&category=Top+Apps+Healthcare+%26+Fitness+Genre&start_date%5Bmonth%5D=4&start_date%5Bday%5D=5&start_date%5Byear%5D=2012 So I took your script and tried to adapt it to the new adress. Because the page number is now inside the URL, I tried to make the right changes. But it doesn't work. Do you have an idea of what to change?

Comment: Here's the edited code I tried: https://docs.google.com/document/d/11qN3iiNduT4w0jTysvoNgnJWffH0R_1mRGKyd9OGcgs/edit

Comment: Hi enzolito, I'm glad you like the solution!  As for the history, I would say you can either include the date filters into the URL and manipulate them as needed.  However, if you need them to be static, then you could simply just copy/paste as values into another worksheet and title the worksheet April-2012 or whatever.  Also, I believe your modified code for Fitness doesn't work because you have to be a member of "Pro" to see those results.  If you are, maybe you can login first, then run the query, but I'm not sure it will work because Excel might not make use of your cookies.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your help, it is hugely appreciated! By history, I simply mean that I want to run this script every day, and store the results. That way I can graph the results over time.   The code I wrote is not about historical data (I posted it a day ago so it appeared as such), it is about getting the exact same ranking in a precise category.

Comment: This link will work for one day only, it's the ranking of free apps in the health and fitness category. http://www.appdata.com/leaderboard/app_store_apps?list_select=app_store&type=Free&device=iPhone&country_id=95&category=Top+Apps+Healthcare+%26+Fitness+Genre&start_date%5Bmonth%5D=4&start_date%5Bday%5D=6&start_date%5Byear%5D=2012 This is what I am trying to get in Excel now. The only change is that the page number is in the middle of the URL.

Comment: I think I know what you're after.  I changed the code to make a static copy after the query is run.  It saves the values, but it's still up to you to run the code manually and save the workbook.  If you want an automated script to run daily, you can create a C# executable that does this and then setup a Windows Scheduled Task to run it daily, but that's probably for another thread :)

Comment: Joseph, thanks a lot for all your help, really. I have a tiny problem though: You wrote a script that works for a url with a page number in the end. I would like to run it with a page number embedded in the url, such as this one http://www.appdata.com/leaderboard/app_store_apps?category=Top+Apps+Healthcare+%26+Fitness+Genre&country_id=95&device=&fanbase=0&list_select=app_store&metric_select=mau&page=2&start_date%5Bday%5D=11&start_date%5Bmonth%5D=4&start_date%5Byear%5D=2012&type=Free      Can you help me fix this?

Comment: You're welcome.  As for your issue, that's easy :) you can just move the "&page=2" at the end.  The website doesn't care where "&page=2" is in the URL as long as it's after the question mark "?".

Answer (score 1):

Here's something you could do, although it's not exactly what you're asking for.

In Excel 2007/2010, go to the Data tab, in the "Get External Data" group, click "From Web".  There will be a place to enter in a url, enter this one in there:
http://www.appdata.com/leaderboard/app_store_apps?fanbase=0&id=3781-top-free-apps&metric_select=mau&page=1

It's the same one you showed, but with the page set to 1 in the url. There will be a yellow box with a black arrow that points at the table you want to look at. Click on that arrow.

Then it will ask you to place it in your workbook. I put it in Sheet2 (if you choose a different sheet, you have to adjust the code by replacing Sheet2 with your worksheet's name).  This added a QueryTable that will show the data you want into Excel's cells.

You can then add VBA code to cycle through the pages.  Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to go to the Visual Basic Editor.  Create a new module and paste this code in there:

```
Sub previousPage()
    Call switchPage(-1)
End Sub


Sub nextPage()
    Call switchPage(1)
End Sub

Sub switchPage(num As Integer)
    Dim q As QueryTable
    Set q = Sheet2.QueryTables(1)
    Dim currentPage As String
    Dim nextPage As String
    currentPage = Mid(q.Connection, InStr(1, q.Connection, "page=", vbTextCompare) + Len("page="), 2)
    If (IsNumeric(currentPage)) Then
        nextPage = CInt(currentPage) + num
    End If
    q.Connection = "URL;http://www.appdata.com/leaderboard/app_store_apps?fanbase=0&id=3781-top-free-apps&metric_select=mau&page=" & nextPage
    q.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End Sub
```

What this code does is cycle through the pages.  When `nextPage()` is run, it will change the URL to go to Page 2.  You get the idea.

From here, you can add buttons above the table in Sheet2 and connect them to `previousPage()` and `nextPage()`.

Comment: thanks a lot, this is great!!! Can you help me have the 400 results (10 pages*40 results/page) in a single sheet, without buttons?